# "not connected" in android bluetooth application

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, emulation

I want to run a bluetooth chat application (sample code [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)).

I run this on android2.2 but it is giving me: `not connected` in device.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

    // Set up the window layout
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);

    // Set up the custom title
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_left_text);
    mTitle.setText(R.string.app_name);
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_right_text);

    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
       }
    }

 @Override
 public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

    // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
    // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    // Otherwise, setup the chat session
    } else {
        if (mChatService == null) setupChat();
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");

    // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
    // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
    // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
    if (mChatService != null) {
        // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
        if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
          // Start the Bluetooth chat services
          mChatService.start();
        }
    }
}

private void setupChat() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

    // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
    mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
    mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
    mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

    // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
    mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
    mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

    // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
    });

    // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
    mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(this, mHandler);

    // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
    mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
    if (mChatService != null) mChatService.stop();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
}

private void ensureDiscoverable() {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "ensure discoverable");
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
        BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
}

/**
 * Sends a message.
 * @param message  A string of text to send.
 */
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}

// The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener =
    new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
        if(D) Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
        return true;
    }
};
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that Bluetooth is not supported by the Emulator. I am facing the same Problem and have to test all Bluetooth stuff on a real device :-(